# Problemas para imprimir una estructura

Tags: c

No me marca errores el programa, sin embargo no me imprime la ultima parte de lo que deseo en la estructura. Me imprime el nombre y el ID, pero no me imprime la carrera ni la clave, que se supone que estan almacenadas en otra estructura y anidada a la nueva. Aqui les dejo las funciones y estructuras.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX 10

struct Carrera{
 char clave[4];
 char nombre[100];
} carrera[MAX];

struct Estudiante{
    char nombre[100];
    int id;
    struct Carrera carrera;
}estudiantes[MAX];

void asignar_carrera(struct Estudiante estudiantes[],struct Carrera carrera[],int matri)
{
    char car[4];
    for(int i=0;estudiantes[i].id;i++)
    {
        if(matri == estudiantes[i].id)
        {
            printf("Ingrese la clave de la carrera: ");
            scanf("%s",car);
            for(int j=0;carrera[j].clave;j++)
            {
                if(car == carrera[j].clave)
                {
                    strcpy(estudiantes[i].carrera.nombre,carrera[j].nombre);
                    strcpy(estudiantes[i].carrera.clave,carrera[j].clave);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

void mostrarDatos(struct Estudiante estudiantes[],int cant)
{
    for(int i=0;;i++)
    {
        if(i>cant || i> MAX)
            break;
        printf("\nNombre: %s\n",estudiantes[i].nombre);
        printf("ID: %d\n",estudiantes[i].id);
        printf("Clave: %s\n",estudiantes[i].carrera.clave);
        printf("Carrera: %s\n",estudiantes[i].carrera.nombre);
        i++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(car == carrera[j].clave)
```

Las cadenas de caracteres no se comparan así. Es necesario usar una función tipo `strcmp` para comparar cadenas.

La condición que has puesto ahí solo se cumplirá cuando ambos punteros direccionen exactamente la misma dirección de memoria, cuando tu lo que quieres es que se comparen las cadenas que direcciona cada puntero.

La solución, usar `strcmp` o una solución similar:

```
if(strcmp(car, clarrera[j].clave) == 0)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Cierto, vaya error tonto :D. Gracias @PaperBirdMaster